# Can I load a jquery colorbox from a remote page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a page that generates a google map on page load that I would like to call from another page via a link.  Here is how I'm creating the google map inside a colorbox:

```
//  show_map.php

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $.colorbox({width:"643px", height: "653px", inline:true, href:"#map_container"}, function() { 
        $.getJSON('map.php', function(data){
            initialize();
            setMarkers(map, data);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my attempt but something tells me I've headed down the wrong path. Should I use the modal window for something like this or is there a better way?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.show_map').click(function() { 
        $.get("show_map.php", function(data) {
          //  alert(data);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, colorbox is already designed to do what you want to do.  You don't need to use extra ajax calls (it's already built in). Just set the `href` option to your page instead of your inline html (then of course remove the `inline:true` option).  The full code (in the page with the link to your map):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show_map').click(function() {
        $.colorbox({
            href: "show_map.php",
            width:"643px",
            height:"653px"
        });
    })
});
```

You can also load any external page if you add the `iframe: true` option to that code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean yet, but the above code is all the colorbox code you need for the one page.  Do you mean a colorbox in a colorbox? Can you post a link to an example or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Either you use jQuery's .getScript() if the page only contains JavaScript or you can use .load() to insert the page content into the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.show_map').click(function() { 
          $('.some-element').load("show_map.php");
    })
});
```

EDIT: a better approach
have the colorbox inline instead. Saves a round trip to the server.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show_map').colorbox({width:"643px", height: "653px", inline:true, href:"#map_container"}, function() { 
        $.getJSON('map.php', function(data){
            initialize();
            setMarkers(map, data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I thought of that but can I or should I load a colorbox into an element? I assumed this would defeat the purpose of the popup colorbox.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work because map.php lives inside show_map.php (the page I need to call)